# Seamlessly swapping videos

Tags: javascript, html

I was curious what the best way to seamlessly swap from one video to another would be. The overall goal would be to play an intro video, and when that video ends, play a 2nd video of a looping animation.

Which method would work best for this?

1. Creating an event listener that starts the 2nd video and hides the first video as soon as the first video ends
2. OR having it all in one video, where the event listener waits until the end of the video and resets the time to where the loop begins

For the 2nd option, let's say the video is 10s long, the intro part is 4s, and the loop part is 6s. We would wait until the 10s mark and restart at 4s once the video plays through once.

Is there a better way to do this or is one of these options the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I would use method 1. Adding a listener and code to play the second video would be easy:

```
  <video src="video.ogv" id="intro">
      video not supported
    </video>
    <video src="video.ogv" id="loop">
      video not supported
    </video>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var vid = document.getElementById("loop");
   vid.loop = true;
   vid.pause()
    document.getElementById('into').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
        function myHandler(e) {
            vid.play()
        }
    </script>
```

You can then also add Jquery hide and show to make it more seamless.